# How is the orange bar extending from the page top when the site wants to notify me of something called?

Tags: support

When an unregistered user comes to any trilogy or StackExchange-based site there's an orange bar extending from the top of the page saying "First time here?" The same bar is used for various notifications.

How is this user interface element called?

Comment: If you mean the actual name of the item, there's a [discussion for coming up with a proper name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51176/messages-notifications-warnings-are-they-different-or-all-the-same-which-one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [this](http://www.thinkbohemian.com/2010/04/22/stack-overflow-style-notifications-using-jquery/) implimentation out.

Comment: Hmmm... "notification bar" sounds quite generic and can be applied to just anything. I'm really surprised there's no ready name yet.

Comment: It's new and exciting.